# Plotting in java with gnuplot gives me a line

Tags: java, gnuplot

I am programming in java and i have to make a plot with some values. The values i want to plot are being written in a file called "cleanOutput.txt" and they are separated by ";". I am writing the following commands on a script file that goes into GnuPlot:

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(ficheiroComando)) {
                writer.write("set datafile separator \";\"\n");
                writer.write("set size ratio 0.75\n");
                writer.write("set format x \"%.5f\"\n");
                writer.write("set terminal png\n");
                writer.write("set output '" + output + "'\n");
                writer.write("plot [0:30][0:1]'" + input + "' using 1:2 with lines title 'Suscetiveis' lc rgb 'red',\\\n");
                writer.write("'" + input + "' using 1:3 with lines title 'Infetados' lc rgb 'blue',\\\n");
                writer.write("'" + input + "' using 1:4 with lines title 'Recuperados' lc rgb 'green'\n");
            }
```

I can use any external library as this is a school project. Here you have some lines of the document input to give you some context:

```
0,000000;0,500000;0,300000;0,200000;
0,200000;0,501467;0,299024;0,199509;
0,300000;0,502929;0,298052;0,199019;
0,400000;0,504385;0,297084;0,198531;
0,500000;0,505835;0,296121;0,198044;
0,600000;0,507280;0,295162;0,197558;
0,700000;0,508718;0,294207;0,197074;
0,800000;0,510152;0,293257;0,196591;
```

I want to get a plot where the first column is the x and then each of the following columns will be the y, so that i have 3 plots on the same grid. The thing is, i am having trouble with plotting as i am only getting a horizontal line. Anyone can help?

I have tried messing around with changing the columns i am plotting and have tried different scales on the plot.

Comment: try changing the decimal separator from `,` to point `.` - maybe gnuplot does not use the system settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user85421 pointed out in the comments the decimalsign is the problem. Default in gnuplot is typically decimal point `.`.
If you type `show decimalsign` in the gnuplot console you might get something like this:

```
decimalsign for input is  . 
decimalsign for output is . 
degree sign for output is °
```

So, be aware that there is a  decimal sign setting for **input** (input data) and **output** (numbers in the graph). In gnuplot console type `help decimalsign`. It's a bit confusing: `set decimalsign ','` will not set your input data decimal sign to `,`.

If you type:

```
set decimalsign locale "French"   # or "German" will also work
set decimalsign "."
```

and after typing `show decimalsign`, you will get:

```
decimalsign for input is  , 
decimalsign for output is . 
degree sign for output is °
```

Comment: ( *somehow* I believe it is more like `"Portuguese"`, but same answer :-) )

Comment: @user85421 right, `set decimalsign locale "Portuguese"` or `set decimalsign locale "Spanish"` will also work. And `set decimalsign locale "English"` will set it back to decimal point.

Comment: You will probably also need: set datafile separator ";" as the default separator is whitespace. See: help set datafile separator ... oops, I see it is there already

Comment: @helper that is the first *command* being added by the code in the question: `writer.write("set datafile separator \";\"\n");`